# Changing button color in swift causes "exc bad instruction" error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

So I'm trying to allow the user to change the color scheme of my app by clicking a button that calls a method to change all the button colors. My button calls this method:

```
    @IBAction func changeColor(sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.currentTitle == "Green" {
            buttonOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            buttonTwo.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            buttonThree.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            buttonFour.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            buttonFive.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            buttonSix.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            buttonSeven.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            buttonEight.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            buttonNine.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            buttonClear.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            buttonPlus.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            buttonMin.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            buttonEq.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            buttonX.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            buttonDiv.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            buttonSet.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        }

    }
```

But when I run the app and click the button to change the color it gives me a "exc bad instruction" error and prints this to the console: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)"

How can I change the color of a button without causing this error? If I add a '!' to the end to unwrap the optional that doesn't work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: You probably have to reconnect your ibaction

Answer (score 0):

currentTitle is an Optional, so you should be doing this:

```
    if let currentTitle = sender.currentTitle {
        if currentTitle == "Green" {
            // set button colors here
        }
    }
```

Comment: that's not what was causing the error. as I said, I get the error when I try to change the background color of the button, not when I check what current title is. the line causing the problem is "buttonOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()"

Comment: You didn't say what line was causing the problem. Phrase your question better.